Bridging On-chain Data with LLM Models: Retrieving Token Information (Solidity + GPT)

I'm developing a Solidity token and exploring ways to leverage Large
Language Models (LLMs) like GPT to answer user queries about the
token's data directly within the application. Ideally, I'd like the
LLM to access information like current supply and total staked users.
However, I understand the limitations of directly connecting smart
contracts to off-chain models.


You can think any on-chain query information as a normal JSON/RPC query an LLM would do. So if you have LLM that can fetch JSON data over HTTP, and somehow interpret this, then you have most part figured out. Blockchain should not be different from any other industry.

Thanks @MikkoOhtamaa, Can you tell me from where I can get the smart contract token data for the model ? One approach I'm aware of involves creating public functions within a smart contract to serve as endpoints. These endpoints can then be accessed by making calls to them from web3.js. Do you know other best way to get the smart contract data for the AI model ?

You can get data from any Ethereum node. https://ethereumnodes.com

Alright thanks @MikkoOhtamaa

Generally, all blockchain data is public. Accessing data is not a problem. Defining the query is.

correct @MikkoOhtamaa

Hello Awais Ahmad
Here is an example using Chainlink Functions:
Prompt AI for a response
You can learn more in the Chainlink Developer Portal

Thanks for the answer @Solange Gueiros, can you tell me from where I can get the smart contract token data for the model ?

One approach I'm aware of involves creating public functions within a smart contract to serve as endpoints. These endpoints can then be accessed by making calls to them from web3.js. Do you know other best way to get the smart contract data for the AI model ?
